# C# Linq Group By Statement results in some sub group for each grouping key

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Sorry for asking may be trivial question , but I was recently playing with Linq group by operator and there is one thing I dont quite able to understand..

Lets say I have some initialised data like that:

```
#region Initialisation
            IList<Customer> listOfCustomers = new List<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer(){ Id = 1, Name = "Customer1"},
                new Customer(){ Id = 2, Name = "Customer2"},
                new Customer(){ Id = 3, Name = "Customer3"},
                new Customer(){ Id = 4, Name = "Customer4"},

            };
            
            IList<Orders> listOfOrders = new List<Orders>()
            {
                new Orders(){ Id = 1, OrderName = "Order1", Cost = 1, CustomerId = 1},
                new Orders(){ Id = 2, OrderName = "Order2", Cost = 2, CustomerId = 2},
                new Orders(){ Id = 3, OrderName = "Order2_2", Cost = 2, CustomerId = 2},
                new Orders(){ Id = 4, OrderName = "Order3", Cost = 3, CustomerId = 3},
                new Orders(){ Id = 5, OrderName = "Order4", Cost = 4, CustomerId = -1},

            };


#endregion
```

Then I am trying to write group by statement and simply group by "Customer Name" (i.e get all orders per each customer):

```
var groupsByCustName = (from cust in listOfCustomers
                                join order in listOfOrders on cust.Id equals order.CustomerId
                                into finalResult
                                group finalResult by cust.Name).ToList();
            //into grouped select grouped;
            
            foreach (var group in groupsByCustName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(group.Count());
                //Why I need second foreach  here in order to get to orders in group?...
                foreach (var group2 in group)
                {
                    foreach (var order in group2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(order.OrderName);
                    }
                }




            }
```

What I dont understand here is why each group under key has just one record, and why in order to get to orders I need to have 2 foreach (i.e get enumerator of enumerator...)

Really appreciate if you could direct me in the right direction to understand that..

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Because you're effectively grouping twice; once with the `into` and once with the `group by`

Comment: Because `GroupJoin` (`select - into`) already creates a group of orders per customer. You don't need the `GroupBy` (`group by`). Try what happens if you remove it.

Comment: Incidentally, may I recommend you do *not* name classes in the plural; it's a recipe for confusion. `class Order`, `List<Order> Orders`